# Adding multiple values from a filtered list to a string which will then be used to create an email list

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I am trying to create a string using VBA that includes all visible values after being filtered in cells B8 to B1129 separated by a semicolon. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Have you attempted any sort of code?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934184/excel-vba-build-a-comma-delimited-string, `s = join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose([b8:b41129]), ";")`

Answer (score 0):

If filter is already applied, you can use following code (the result is stored in the cell `C2`):

```
 Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim res As String
    Dim c As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    'change "Sheet1" to your cheet name'
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range("B8:B1129").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        For Each c In rng
            If Not ISEmpty(c) Then res = res & c.Value & ", "
        Next
        res = Left(res, Len(res) - 2)

        .Range("C2") = res
    End With

End Sub
```

or you can apply autofilter directly from VBA:

```
 Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim res As String
    Dim c As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    'change "Sheet1" to your cheet name'
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*searchText*"

        Set rng = .Range("B8:B1129").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        For Each c In rng
            If Not ISEmpty(c) Then res = res & c.Value & ", "
        Next
        res = Left(res, Len(res) - 2)

        .Range("C2") = res
    End With

End Sub
```