# Convert range to comma delimited string

Tags: vba, excel

If I had a column like this:

```
Col1
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

How can I convert it to a string like this?:

```
"abc,def,ghi,jkl"
```

Comment: Non VBA methods would be to use `&` or `Concatenate` function.

Comment: In Office 2016 see CONCAT and TEXTJOIN, https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/02/05/new-ways-to-concatenate-text-in-excel-2016-with-concat-and-textjoin/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `Join()` function to join all the elements of a 1 dimensional array with a delimiter.

The `Transpose()` function is used below to form the dimensional array (this approach works on a single column or row).

```
Sub Main()
    Dim arr
    arr = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A2:A5").Value), ",")
    MsgBox arr
End Sub
```

or as a UDF

```
Public Function Merge(r As Range) As String
    Merge = Join(Application.Transpose(r.Value), ",")
End Function
```

Comment: [This works only with cells in a single column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934184/build-a-comma-delimited-string), but not with cells in a  single row like `arr=Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:B1").Value), ",")`

Comment: @nixda I think you would want to transpose the range twice in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you need heavier machinery use one of the solutions provided in the answer below. I had similar challenge for ranges containing milion of cells. In such cases `JOIN` will lead to crash.

Check the question here:
[Turn Excel range into VBA string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597999/turn-excel-range-into-vba-string)

I have tested all the approaches provided in the above link. Solutions based on function `JOIN` have slow performance, or even lead to crash.

Ordinary **loop through** all the cells is way faster than `JOIN` function. The **sting builder** in accepted answer is even faster. With string builder, the strings consisting of millions of cells are build in seconds. This is the solution I have end up with.

Answer (score 0):

Double-transpose works for doing string join on single-row values. Thanks @user2140173 and @brettdj!

`debug.print join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:G1").Value)),",")`

Answer (score 0):

```vba
Public Function COLSASLIST(Rng As Range) As String
    Dim tempStr1 As String
    tempStr1 = Replace(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Rng.Value)), ","), ",,", ""), ",,", ",")
    If Right(tempStr1, 1) = "," Then tempStr1 = Left(tempStr1, Len(tempStr1) - 1)
    COLSASLIST = tempStr1
End Function

Public Function ROWSASLIST(Rng As Range) As String
    Dim tempStr1 As String
    tempStr1 = Replace(Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Rng.Value), ","), ",,", ","), ",,", ",")
    If Right(tempStr1, 1) = "," Then tempStr1 = Left(tempStr1, Len(tempStr1) - 1)
    ROWSASLIST = tempStr1
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the new dynamic worksheetfunction `TextJoin()` of **Microsoft 365/Excel2019 (+/-Mac) and Excel for the Web** you can build a udf with the following range arguments

- (1) a column *or*
- (2) a row *or even*
- (3) a contiguous range input (e.g. "A2:C5")

The optional 2nd argument `ExcludeBlanks` allows to omit blank values.

The function **result** is a comma separated list (important for case `(3)`: the reading order is *row wise*).

```
Function Rng2List(rng As Range, Optional ExcludeBlanks As Boolean = True) As String
    Rng2List = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", ExcludeBlanks, rng)
End Function
```

See help at [Textjoin function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)