# Split string into table given row delimiter and column delimiter in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

How to split string containing matrix into table in SQL Server? String has columns and row delimiters.

Suppose I have a string:

```
declare @str varchar(max)='A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';
```

Expected results (in three separate columns):

```
+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| D | E | F |
+---+---+---+
| X | Y | Z |
+---+---+---+
```

I am looking for general solution which has not defined number of columns and rows. So the string:

```
declare @str varchar(max)='A,B;D,E';
```

will be split into table with two columns:

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| D | E |
+---+---+
```

**My efforts.** My first idea was to use dynamic SQL which turns the string into:
`insert into dbo.temp values (...)` This approach although very fast has a minor drawback because it requires creating a table with the right number of columns first. I have presented this method in [**the answer to my own question below**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39758478/1903793) just to keep the question short.

Another idea would be to write down the string to a CSV file on the server and then `bulk insert` from it. Though I do not know how to do it and what would be performance of first and second idea.

The reason why I asked the question is because I want to import data from Excel to SQL Server. As I have experimented with different ADO approaches, this method of sending matrix-string is a landslide victory, especially when the length of the string increases. I asked a younger twin brother of the question here: **[Turn Excel range into VBA string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597999/turn-excel-range-into-vba-string)**  where you will find suggestions how to prepare such a string from Excel range.

**Bounty** I decided to award **Matt**. I weighed highly **Sean Lange's**  answer. Thank you Sean. I liked Matt's answer for its simplicity and shortness. Different approaches apart from Matt's and Sean's could be in parallel use so for the time being I am not accepting any answer (update: Finally, after a few months, I have accepted Matt's answer). I wish to thank **Ahmed Saeed** for his idea with VALUES, for it is a nice evolution of the answer I began with. Of course, it is no match for the Matt's or Sean's. I upvoted every answer. I will appreciate any feedback from you on using these methods. Thank you for the quest.

Comment: Downvote could also be due to not showing what he's tried.

Comment: You could assume a maximum number of columns, say 100, and write a  CLR TVF to split the string, e.g. Based on http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/04/28/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable.aspx

Comment: I wish I could call up some widely respected SQL experts who might share their opinion on provided answers. Some of your answers go beyond my current knowledge. I may not be able to swallow them up and digest in just few days left for bounty period. So I kindly ask any of you with high reputation. Please share your comments on the answers. Help me to award the bounty justly.

Comment: Just to be clear... do you need to insert the matrix to existing table or just *display* it like table/grid?

Comment: @Susilo Yes, I need to insert it to another table. But inserting it in a way like `select * into table` (like in the table creation) would be an advantage over `insert into table select * ...` because the first way is more convenient. See further remarks on that in my answer.

Comment: in your answer, the matrix data inserted to temp table.. is that necessary? and its already a good solution. but what really need to achieve then? a dynamic temp table or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the easier ways is to convert the string to XML based on replacing your delimiters.

```
declare @str varchar(max)='A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';
DECLARE @xmlstr XML
SET @xmlstr = CAST(('<rows><row><col>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,';','</col></row><row><col>'),',','</col><col>') + '</col></row></rows>') AS XML)

SELECT
    t.n.value('col[1]','CHAR(1)') as Col1
    ,t.n.value('col[2]','CHAR(1)') as Col2
    ,t.n.value('col[3]','CHAR(1)') as Col3
FROM
    @xmlstr.nodes ('/rows/row') AS t(n)
```

- Format string as XML `<rows><row><col></col><col></col></row><row><col></col><col></col></row></rows>`  Basically you need to add the beginning and ending tags then replace the column delimiter with the column tags and the row delimiter with both column and row tags
- .nodes is a method on the xml data type that "is useful when you want to shred an xml data type instance into relational data" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx
- `as t(n)` tells you how you will end up accessing the XML row and column.  t being the table alias and n being the node alias (kind of like a row).  so t.n.value() gets a particular row
- `COL[1]` means get the first `COL` tag in the row it is 1 based so 2 is the next then 3 etc.
- `CHAR(1)` is a datatype definition meaning 1 character and was based on your example data having only 1 character per column.  you may noticed I made it `VARCHAR(MAX)` in the dynamic query because if data type is unknown then you will want more flexibility.

Or dynamically

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max)='A,B,C,D,E;F,G,H,I,J;K,L,M,N,O';
DECLARE @NumOfColumns INT
SET @NumOfColumns = (LEN(@str) - LEN(REPLACE(@str,',',''))) / (LEN(@str) - LEN(REPLACE(@str,';','')) + 1) + 1

DECLARE @xmlstr XML
SET @xmlstr = CAST(('<rows><row><col>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,';','</col></row><row><col>'),',','</col><col>') + '</col></row></rows>') AS XML)

DECLARE @ParameterDef NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@XMLInputString xml'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '

DECLARE @i INT = 1

WHILE @i <= @NumOfColumns
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = @SQL + IIF(@i > 1,',','') + 't.n.value(''col[' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'',''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') as Col' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10))

    SET @i = @i + 1
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM
    @XMLInputString.nodes (''/rows/row'') AS t(n)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,@ParameterDef,@XMLInputString = @xmlstr
```

Comment: Looks very promising to me. Could you please explain the logic of your first static solution? What for you are replacing something and what is `.nodes`? I am not familiar with XML.

Comment: What is `'CHAR(1)'` for in the line `t.n.value('col[1]','CHAR(1)') as Col1`?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin see update CHAR(1) is just a datatype because you were only using 1 character

Comment: I am looking for general solution. Can I use NVARCHAR(max) instead of CHAR(1)?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin yes as I showed in the dynamic you can change the datatype.  I put VARCHAR(MAX) but all you have to do is add an N on front. which I just did.  I do caution you though about using a solution like this unless you have to!  This doesn't account for text qualifiers which allow for delimiters to be within a field etc.  If you are looking at this as a solution to extract transform load data honestly don't use some of the other tools such as ssis, open_rowset, etc.

Comment: Just for others who use SQL 2008 R2. Replace `IFF` line with `SET @SQL = @SQL + (case when @i >1 then ',' else '' end) + 't.n.value(''col[' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'',''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') as Col' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10))`

Comment: @Matt I posted a new answer here which you might find interesting.

Comment: @SeanLange looking good, I would be curious at some point to see performance differences on a few answers.  The split split cross technique was also used by Siyual in his answer, but your splitting functions vary dramatically and then he choose pivot where as you have gone with conditional aggregation with tally table.  I will run the code and test parts of it later when I can to make sure I comprehend full technique.  But cheers good answer +1, and good use of supporting articles and documentation for the set based splitter

Comment: @Matt to be honest there are only 2 answers worth testing. Yours and mine. The one by Siyual uses a loop splitter and I am not going to bother testing performance there, it will lose with even moderate sized data. And the one from Shrikant creates a permanent table which means it will only work once unless you also drop that table and creating and dropping tables for this is also kind of pointless to test. If I can find some time I will take your dynamic solution and mine and run it through some testing.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin if my answer or another one has answered your question please consider accepting it so others now you have found a solution and reputation points are awarded.  thanks. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @MAtt (1) What are limitations to your solution? I know that there are some special characters in the string which cannot be used in XML. Anything else? (2) The input string itself can be nvarchar(max), can't it? (3) No limit on column number or row number?

Comment: @Matt I do not understand the construction of the last line of your code. `EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,@ParameterDef,@XMLInputString = @xmlstr` Why there are 3 parameters to be executed?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin `@SQL` query we generate, `@ParameterDef` this variable contains definition of variable we need to use in query. The last part is passing `@xmlstr` into `sp_executesql` as variable defined in `@ParameterDef`

Answer (score 6):

OK this puzzle intrigued me so I decided to see if I could do this without any looping. There are a couple of prerequisites for this to work. The first is we will assume you have some sort of tally table. In case you don't have that here is the code for mine. I keep this on every system I use.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

The second piece of this puzzle is needing a set based string splitter. My preference for this is the uber fast Jeff Moden splitter. One caveat is that it will only work with varchar values up to 8,000. This is plenty for most delimited strings I work with. You can find Jeff Moden's splitter (DelimitedSplit8K) here.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Last but not least is that the technique I am using here is a dynamic cross tab. This is something else I learned from Jeff Moden. He has a great article on the subject here.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Putting all of this together you can come up with something like this which will be really fast and will scale well.

```
declare @str varchar(max)='A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';

declare @StaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = 
'declare @str varchar(max)=''' + @str + ''';with OrderedResults as
    (
        select s.ItemNumber
            , s.Item as DelimitedValues
            , x.ItemNumber as RowNum
            , x.Item
        from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@str, '';'') s
        cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.Item, '','') x
    )
    select '

declare @DynamicPortion nvarchar(max) = '';
declare @FinalStaticPortion nvarchar(2000) = ' from OrderedResults group by ItemNumber';

select @DynamicPortion = @DynamicPortion + 
    ', MAX(Case when RowNum = ' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + ' then Item end) as Column' + CAST(N as varchar(6)) + CHAR(10)
from cteTally t
where t.N <= (select MAX(len(Item) - LEN(replace(Item, ',', ''))) + 1
                from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@str, ';')
            )

declare @SqlToExecute nvarchar(max) = @StaticPortion + stuff(@DynamicPortion, 1, 1, '') + @FinalStaticPortion
exec sp_executesql @SqlToExecute
```

--EDIT--

Here is the DelimitedSplit8K function in case the link becomes invalid.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

Comment: (1) Can you please explain what the tally is for? (2) If it is possible for you, can you please tell what is the advantage of your solution over the xml approach by Matt?

Comment: Tally is a table of sequential numbers. It is extremely handy for avoiding loops in situations like this. You can read more about tally tables and what they can be used for here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/ They have been called the swiss army knife of t-sql because they are so useful in so many situations.

Comment: Honestly the solution from Matt is pretty solid. I vehemently dislike looping and I wanted to demonstrate how this could be solved with no loops. Matt's solution is very comparable performance wise. In my testing it even scaled pretty close to the solution I posted. If it was my code I would probably choose this approach because I am so biased against using loops. They of course have their place but a set based approach to this will scale better on super large datasets.

Comment: (1) What is the usefulness of tally here in your code? It is needed for number of columns, rows, something else? (2) Does the limitation of the string type to varchar(8000) can swallow nvarchar(8000)? (4) How many characters would that be? (3) Is this "uber fast" splitter not a bottle neck of that solution? You have criticized Siyual answer in the comment on splitters http://stackoverflow.com/a/39752753/1903793

Comment: 1) - the tally table is used to determine the dynamic number of columns instead of using a while loop. 2) - What?? 4) - 8000 3) Sure the splitter is the bottleneck because sql is not built to do this type of thing. But it is light years faster than that awful while loop proposal in the answer you linked.

Comment: It would be better to post some code for the DelimitedSplit8K function in case the link to Jeff Moden's code becomes invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Below code should work in SQL Server. It uses Common Table Expression and Dynamic SQL with little manipulations. Just assign the string value to `@str` variable and execute the complete code in one go. Since it uses CTE, it is easy to analyze data at each step.

```
Declare @Str varchar(max)= 'A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RawData') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #RawData;
;WITH T_String AS
(
    SELECT  RIGHT(@Str,LEN(@Str)-CHARINDEX(';',@Str,1)) AS RawString, LEFT(@Str,CHARINDEX(';',@Str,1)-1) AS RowString, 1 AS CounterValue,  len(@Str) - len(replace(@Str, ';', '')) AS RowSize
    --
    UNION ALL
    --
    SELECT  IIF(CHARINDEX(';',RawString,1)=0,NULL,RIGHT(RawString,LEN(RawString)-CHARINDEX(';',RawString,1))) AS RawString, IIF(CHARINDEX(';',RawString,1)=0,RawString,LEFT(RawString,CHARINDEX(';',RawString,1)-1)) AS RowString, CounterValue+1 AS CounterValue, RowSize AS RowSize
    FROM    T_String AS r
    WHERE   CounterValue <= RowSize
)
,T_Columns AS
(
    SELECT  RowString AS RowValue, RIGHT(a.RowString,LEN(a.RowString)-CHARINDEX(',',a.RowString,1)) AS RawString, 
            LEFT(a.RowString,CHARINDEX(',',a.RowString,1)-1) AS RowString, 1 AS CounterValue,  len(a.RowString) - len(replace(a.RowString, ',', '')) AS RowSize
    FROM    T_String AS a
    --WHERE a.CounterValue = 1
    --
    UNION ALL
    --
    SELECT  RowValue, IIF(CHARINDEX(',',RawString,1)=0,NULL,RIGHT(RawString,LEN(RawString)-CHARINDEX(',',RawString,1))) AS RawString, IIF(CHARINDEX(',',RawString,1)=0,RawString,LEFT(RawString,CHARINDEX(',',RawString,1)-1)) AS RowString, CounterValue+1 AS CounterValue, RowSize AS RowSize
    FROM    T_Columns AS r
    WHERE   CounterValue <= RowSize
)
,T_Data_Prior2Pivot AS 
(
    SELECT  c.RowValue, c.RowString, c.CounterValue
    FROM    T_Columns AS c
    INNER JOIN
            T_String AS r
        ON  r.RowString = c.RowValue
)
SELECT  *
INTO    #RawData
FROM    T_Data_Prior2Pivot;

DECLARE @columnNames VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@sqlQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @columnNames = COALESCE(@columnNames+', ['+CAST(CounterValue AS VARCHAR)+']','['+CAST(CounterValue AS VARCHAR)+']') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CounterValue FROM #RawData) T
PRINT @columnNames

SET @sqlQuery = '
SELECT  '+@columnNames+'
FROM    ( SELECT * FROM #RawData 
        ) AS b
PIVOT   (MAX(RowString) FOR CounterValue IN ('+@columnNames+')) AS p
'

EXEC (@sqlQuery);
```

[image]

Below is Stats screenshot for above query from http://statisticsparser.com/.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
**--Using dynamic queries..**


declare @str varchar(max)='A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';

declare @cc int

select @cc = len (substring (@str, 0, charindex(';', @str))) - len(replace(substring (@str, 0, charindex(';', @str)), ',', ''))

declare @ctq varchar(max) = 'create table t('


declare @i int = 0 

while @i <= @cc
begin

        select @ctq = @ctq + 'column' + char(65 + @i) + ' varchar(max), '
        select  @i = @i + 1
end

select  @ctq = @ctq + ')'

select  @str = '''' + replace(@str, ',', ''',''') + ''''

select @str = 'insert t select ' + @str

select  @str = replace (@str, ';', ''' union all select ''')

exec(@ctq)

exec(@str)
```

Comment: This works but talk about inefficient. There is no need for looping or dynamic sql for this kind of thing.

Comment: @SeanLange what do you mean no need for dynamic sql if the number of columns are unknown how would you propose to do it without dynamically building the query?  Also the good part for his answer and my dynamic one is that the loop is simply for the column definition NOT for the data manipulation

Comment: @SeanLange Trow the dynamic cross method in as an answer I wouldn't mind seeing what you have in mind and seeing more options for people to choose. I found the xml method to probably be the easiest to code but the XML performance is not always great.  I highly doubt a loop just for column definitions is going to put much overhead into a solution probably...Cartesian join might cause some stress... I hate loops too generally and I guess we could change how we define our columns to a recursive cte and then concatenate the rows thinking loop may end up faster for this light weight use.....

Comment: Agreed. Recursive ctes can really chew up your server when not used properly. I have some actual work I need to spend some cycles on but I will definitely get back to this one as I find this challenge an interesting one.

Comment: @SeanLange .. sorry... but i am new to stack overflow.. and i had taken question as a game .. :-)

Comment: @ShrikantKumbhar this is actually a good answer, not one I would have thought of.  I would only enhance by using temp table [tt] instead and testing for the existence of the tt.  but it really is a pretty solid technique and especially if OP wants to persist data for more than 1 operation may be the best technique.

Answer (score 2):

I post the answer to my question just to extend the question, to show what I use at the time when I ask the question.

The idea is to change the original string into:

```
insert into dbo.temp values (...)(...)
```

Here is a stored procedure for that:

```
create PROC [dbo].[StringToMatrix] 
(
 @String nvarchar(max)
,@DelimiterCol nvarchar(50)=','
,@DelimiterRow nvarchar(50)=';'
,@InsertTable nvarchar(200) ='dbo.temp'
,@Delete int=1 --delete is ON
) 
AS
BEGIN
set nocount on;

set @String = case when right(@String,len(@DelimiterRow))=@DelimiterRow then left(@string,len(@String)-len(@DelimiterRow)) else @String end --if present, removes the last row delimiter at the very end of string
set @String = replace(@String,@DelimiterCol,''',''')
set @String = replace(@String,@DelimiterRow,'''),'+char(13)+char(10)+'(''')   
set @String = 'insert into '+@InsertTable+' values '+char(13)+char(10)+'(''' +@String +''');'
set @String = replace(@String,'''''','null') --optional, changes empty strings to nulls

set @String = CASE 
    WHEN @Delete = 1 THEN 'delete from '+@InsertTable+';'+char(13)+char(10)+@String 
    ELSE @String 
    END

--print @String
exec (@String)
END
```

Executing the proc with the code:

```
exec [dbo].[StringToMatrix] 'A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z'
```

generates the following @String:

```
delete from [dbo].[temp];
insert into [dbo].[temp] values 
('A','B','C'),
('D','E','F'),
('X','Y','Z');
```

which in final line of proc is dynamically executed.

The solution requires creating appropriate `dbo.table` first, to which the values will be inserted. It is a minor drawback. Thus the solution is not so dynamic as it could be if it had a structure: `select * into dbo.temp`. Nevertheless I want to share this solution because it works, it is fast, simple, and maybe it will be an inspiration for some other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another approach.

```
Declare @Str varchar(max)='A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';

Select A.*,B.*
 Into  #TempSplit
 From (Select RowNr=RetSeq,String=RetVal From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@Str,';')) A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.String,',') B

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Select @SQL = @SQL+Concat(',Col',RetSeq,'=max(IIF(RetSeq=',RetSeq,',RetVal,null))') 
 From  (Select Distinct RetSeq from #TempSplit) A 
 Order By A.RetSeq

Set @SQL ='
If Object_ID(''[dbo].[Temp]'', ''U'') IS NOT NULL 
  Drop Table [dbo].[Temp]; 

Select ' + Stuff(@SQL,1,1,'') + ' Into [dbo].[Temp] From #TempSplit  Group By RowNr Order By RowNr 
'
Exec(@SQL)

Select * from Temp
```

Returns

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       B       C
D       E       F
X       Y       Z
```

Now, this does require a parser which is listed below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Just to illustrate, the First Parse will return

```
RowNr   String
1       A,B,C
2       D,E,F
3       X,Y,Z
```

This is then parsed again via a `CROSS APPLY`, which returns the following and is stored in a temp table

```
RowNr   String  RetSeq  RetVal
1       A,B,C   1       A
1       A,B,C   2       B
1       A,B,C   3       C
2       D,E,F   1       D
2       D,E,F   2       E
2       D,E,F   3       F
3       X,Y,Z   1       X
3       X,Y,Z   2       Y
3       X,Y,Z   3       Z
```

> **EDIT:  Or Just for fun**

```
Declare @String varchar(max)='A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '',@Col int = Len(Left(@String,CharIndex(';',@String)-1))-Len(replace(Left(@String,CharIndex(';',@String)-1),',',''))+1
Select  @SQL = @SQL+SQL From (Select Top (@Col) SQL=Concat(',xRow.xNode.value(''col[',N,']'',''varchar(max)'') as Col',N) From (Select N From (Values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) N(N) ) N ) A
Select  @SQL = Replace('Declare @XML XML = Cast((''<row><col>'' + Replace(Replace(''[getString]'','';'',''</col></row><row><col>''),'','',''</col><col>'') + ''</col></row>'') as XML);Select '+Stuff(@SQL,1,1,'')+' From @XML.nodes(''/row'') AS xRow(xNode) ','[getString]',@String)
Exec (@SQL)
```

Returns

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       B       C
D       E       F
X       Y       Z
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved without the need for temporary tables, views, loops or xml. First you can create a string splitter function based on a tally table as per example below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
   @delimitedString VARCHAR(MAX),
   @delimiter VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@delimitedString,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@delimitedString,t.N,1) = @delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) AS Nr
         ,Item = SUBSTRING(@delimitedString, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@delimitedString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
```

Then use the splitter function to first split the strings based on the row delimiters. Then apply the splitter function again on each row using the OUTER APPLY statement. Finally pivot the result. 
Since the number of columns is unknown the query will have to be executed as dynamic SQL as per example below:

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(max) = 'A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1;A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2;A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,G3;A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4;A5,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,G5;A6,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6;A7,B7,C7,D7,E7,F7,G7;A8,B8,C8,D8,E8,F8,G8;A9,B9,C9,D9,E9,F9,G9;A10,B10,C10,D10,E10,F10,G10;A11,B11,C11,D11,E11,F11,G11;A12,B12,C12,D12,E12,F12,G12;A13,B13,C13,D13,E13,F13,G13;A14,B14,C14,D14,E14,F14,G14;A15,B15,C15,D15,E15,F15,G15;A16,B16,C16,D16,E16,F16,G16;A17,B17,C17,D17,E17,F17,G17;A18,B18,C18,D18,E18,F18,G18;A19,B19,C19,D19,E19,F19,G19;A20,B20,C20,D20,E20,F20,G20'

-- First determine the columns names. Since the string can be potential very long we don’t want to parse the entire string to determine how many columns 
-- we have, instead get sub string of main string up to first row delimiter.
DECLARE @firstRow VARCHAR(max) = LEFT(@source, CHARINDEX(';', @source) - 1);
DECLARE @columnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- Use string splitter function on sub string to determine column names.
SELECT @columnNames = STUFF(( 
                                SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR(10)))
                                FROM        [dbo].[SplitString](@firstRow, ',') Items
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

-- Next build dynamic query that will generate our matrix table.
-- CTE first split string by row delimiters then it applies the string split function again on each row.  
DECLARE @pivotQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) ='
;WITH CTE_SplitData AS
(
SELECT       R.Nr AS [Row]
            ,C.[Columns]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY R.Nr ORDER BY R.Item) AS ColumnNr
FROM        [dbo].[SplitString](@source, '';'') R
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT  Item AS [Columns]
                FROM    [dbo].[SplitString](R.Item, '','') 
            ) C
)
-- Pivoted reuslt
SELECT * FROM
(  
     SELECT * 
     FROM   CTE_SplitData
)as T
PIVOT 
(
     max(T.[Columns])
     for T.[ColumnNr] in (' +  @columnNames + ')
) as P'


EXEC sp_executesql  @pivotQuery,
          N'@source VARCHAR(MAX)',  
          @source = @source;        -- Pass the source string to be split as a parameter to the dynamic query.
```

Answer (score 2):

Some XML with pivoting and dynamic SQL.

1. Replace `,` and `;` with tags `p` and `row`, to cast it as XML,
2. Then count the number of columns and put it in `@i`,
3. With `colsPiv` CTE we generate a string and put it into `@col`, string is like `,[1],[2],..[n]` it will be used in pivoting,
4. Than we generate a dynamic pivot query, and execute it. We also pass 2 parameters XML and column count.

Here is the query:

```
--declare @str varchar(max)='A,B;D,E;X,Y',
declare @str varchar(max)='A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z',
        @x xml,
        @col nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max),
        @params nvarchar(max) = '@x xml, @i int',
        @i int

SELECT  @x = CAST('<row>'+REPLACE(('<p>'+REPLACE(@str,',','</p><p>')+'</p>'),';','</p></row><row><p>')+'</row>' as xml),
        @str = REPLACE(@str,';',',;')+',;', 
        @i =  (LEN(@str)-LEN(REPLACE(@str,',','')))/(LEN(@str)-LEN(REPLACE(@str,';','')))

;WITH colsPiv AS (
    SELECT 1 as col
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col+1
    FROM colsPiv
    WHERE col < @i
)

SELECT @col = (
    SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(col)
    FROM colsPiv
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

SELECT @sql = N'
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RowNum,
            t.c.value(''.'',''nvarchar(max)'') as [Values]
    FROM @x.nodes(''/row/p'') as t(c)
)

SELECT '+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+'
FROM (
    SELECT  RowNum - CASE WHEN RowNum%@i = 0 THEN @i ELSE RowNum%@i END Seq ,
            CASE WHEN RowNum%@i = 0 THEN @i ELSE RowNum%@i END as [ColumnNum],
            [Values]
    FROM cte
) as t
PIVOT (
    MAX([Values]) FOR [ColumnNum] IN ('+STUFF(@col,1,1,'')+')
) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @x = @x, @i = @i
```

Output for `A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z`:

```
1   2   3
A   B   C
D   E   F
X   Y   Z
```

For `A,B;D,E;X,Y`:

```
1   2
A   B
D   E
X   Y
```

Comment: What is a difference between your solution and Matt's with regard to creation of XML string?

Comment: To be honest I scrolled and read all provided answers - then wrote my own :) All the answers used similar but yet different approaches. **Matt** uses while loop to construct query, and get columns directly from XML, I use pivoting, and generate query without loops. **Siyual** used split functions, **John Cappelletti** uses functions with XML and cross applying, **Edmond Quinton** uses split functions with XML and pivoting. I don't like to use functions/while loops/temp tables that is why my answer kicked in!

Comment: After getting more used to pivots in SQL I do appreciate elegance of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

in this solution I'll use string manipulation as much as possible. The procedure will construct a dynamic SQL statement by converting the input string to a form suitable for VALUES keyword, build the column titles by counting the number of columns and generate the required headers. Then, simply execute the constructed SQL statement.

```
Create Proc dbo.Spliter
(
    @str varchar(max), @RowSep char(1), @ColSep char(1)
) 
as
    declare  @FirstRow varchar(max), @hdr varchar(max), @n int, @i int=0

-- Generate the Column names
    set @FirstRow=iif(CHARINDEX(@RowSep, @str)=0, @str, Left(@str, CHARINDEX(@RowSep, @str)-1))

    set @n=LEN(@FirstRow) - len(REPLACE(@FirstRow, @ColSep,''))
    while @i<=@n begin
        Set @hdr= coalesce(@hdr+', ', '') + 'Col' +convert(varchar, @i)
        set @i+=1
    end

--Convert the input string to a form suitable for Values keyword
--i.e. similar to Values(('A'),('B'),('C')),(('D'),('E'),('F')), ...etc
    set @str =REPLACE(@str, @ColSep,'''),(''')
    set @str = 'Values((''' + REPLACE(@str, @RowSep, ''')),((''') + '''))'

    exec('SELECT * FROM (' + @str + ') as t('+@hdr+')')    

-- exec dbo.Spliter 'A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z', ';', ','
```

Method-2:

To overcome the problem of the 1000 rows Values limit as indicated by PrzemyslawRemin, here is a small modification to convert input string to one row xml field and then CROSS APPLY it with its individual elements.

```
Create Proc dbo.Spliter2
(
    @str varchar(max), @RowSep char(1), @ColSep char(1)
) 
as

     declare  @FirstRow varchar(max), @hdr varchar(max), @ColCount int, @i int=0
 , @ColTemplate varchar(max)= 'Col.value(''(./c)[$]'', ''VARCHAR(max)'') AS Col$'

-- Determin the number of columns
    set @FirstRow=iif(CHARINDEX(@RowSep, @str)=0, @str, Left(@str, CHARINDEX(@RowSep, @str)-1))
    set @ColCount = LEN(@FirstRow) - len(REPLACE(@FirstRow, @ColSep,''))

-- Construct Column Headers by replacing the $ with the column number
-- similar to: Col.value('(./c)[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS Col1,     Col.value('(./c)[2]', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS Col2
    while @i<=@ColCount begin
        Set @hdr= coalesce(@hdr+', ', '') + Replace(@ColTemplate, '$', convert(varchar, @i+1))
        set @i+=1
    end

-- Convert the input string to XML format
-- similar to '<r><c>A</c><c>B</c><c>c</c></r> <r><c>D</c><c>E</c><c>f</c>    </r> 
    set @str='<c>'+replace(@str, ',', '</c>'+'<c>')+'</c>'
    set @str='<r>'+replace(@str  , ';', '</c></r><r><c>')+'</r>'

    set @str='SELECT ' +@HDR 
    + ' From(Values(Cast('''+@str+''' as xml))) as t1(x) 
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes(''/r'') as t2(Col)'

    exec( @str)

-- exec dbo.Spliter2 'A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z', ';', ','
```

Comment: This is interesting idea. Does the clause `select * from VALUES(...)` needs `as T(...)`? Are column names mandatory in your attempt?

Comment: The maximum number of rows in one VALUES clause is 1000. So this solution needs some modification for larger data sets.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin, the "select from" require a table alias and column names.

Comment: True, the maximum is 1000 records, I didn't know before, thanks. I guess thats enough for a table contained in a string variable. However, multiple inserts can be used or code modification.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to do this via a dynamic `PIVOT` using a `Split` custom function:

**Split Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(MAX), @delimiter varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(    
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(MAX)   
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int 
SET @index = -1 

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) 
  BEGIN  
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)  
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)  
      BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK  
      END  
    IF (@index > 1)  
      BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))   
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))  
      END  
    ELSE 
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
    END
  RETURN
END

GO
```

**Query**

```
Declare @Str Varchar (Max) = 'A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';
Declare @Sql NVarchar (Max) = '',
        @Cols NVarchar (Max) = '';

;With Rows As
(
    Select      Position, Value As Row
    From        dbo.fn_Split(@str, ';')
), Columns As
(
    Select      Rows.Position   As RowNum,
                Cols.Position   As ColNum,
                Cols.Value      As ColValue 
    From        Rows
    Cross Apply dbo.fn_Split(Row, ',') Cols
)
Select  *
Into    #Columns
From    Columns

Select  @Cols = Stuff(( Select  Distinct ',' + QuoteName(ColNum)
                        From    #Columns
                        For Xml Path(''), Type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                    , 1, 1, '')

Select  @SQL = 'SELECT ' + @Cols + ' FROM #Columns 
Pivot 
(
    Max(ColValue)
    For ColNum In (' + @Cols + ')
) P
Order By RowNum'

Execute (@SQL)
```

**Results**

```
1   2   3
A   B   C
D   E   F
X   Y   Z
```

Comment: I really wish these loop based splitters would stop getting posted by everybody. They are just awful for performance. There are many set based splitters which will blow the doors off these RBAR ones. And even worse is this particular one which is a multi-statement table valued function. These are even slower than a scalar function. You should read this article and throw away that slow looping function. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1):

My solution is using string_split and stuff.. First is example on how it works

```
DECLARE @str varchar(max) = 'A,B,C;D,E,F;X,Y,Z';
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn, *
FROM string_split(@str, ';')),
cte2
AS (SELECT rn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rownum, val.value
FROM cte c
CROSS APPLY string_split(value, ',') val)
SELECT
    [1], [2], [3]
FROM cte2
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR rownum IN ([1], [2], [3])) p
```

Using dynamic sql we can identify the list of columns and it will work for any input

```
declare @str varchar(max)='A,B;D,E;X,Y';
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @cols varchar(max) = ''

;with cte as (
select row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn from string_split( substring(@str,1,charindex(';', @str)-1),',')
) select @cols=concat(@cols,',',quotename(rn)) from cte

select @cols = stuff(@cols,1,1,'')
set @sql = N'
declare @str varchar(max)=''A,B;D,E;X,Y'';
with cte as
(
select row_number() over( order by (select null)) as rn, * from string_split(@str,'';'')
), cte2 as (
select rn, row_number() over(partition by rn order by (select null)) rownum,  val.value from cte c cross apply string_split(value,'','') val
)
select ' +@cols + '
from cte2 
pivot (max(value) for rownum in (' + @cols + ')) p '

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

If you are using SQL Server <2016 then we can write our own split function

Answer (score 0):

The following isn't quite what the OP asked, but it's been handy for me, to export a spreadsheet as CSV (actually Tab-SV) with column headings, and convert it to a SQL Table with correct column names.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.uspDumpMultilinesWithHeaderIntoTable', 'P') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.uspDumpMultilinesWithHeaderIntoTable; 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspDumpMultilinesWithHeaderIntoTable @TableName VARCHAR(32), @Multilines VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RawData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #RawData
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RawDataColumnnames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #RawDataColumnnames
    DECLARE @RowDelim VARCHAR(9) = '&#x0d;'
    DECLARE @ColDelim VARCHAR(9) = CHAR(9)
    DECLARE @MultilinesSafe VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @MultilinesXml XML--VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnNamesAsString VARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000), @ParamDef NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @MultilinesSafe = REPLACE(@Multilines, CHAR(10), '')    -- replace LF
    SET @MultilinesSafe = (SELECT REPLACE(@MultilinesSafe, CHAR(10), '') FOR XML PATH(''))   -- escape any XML confusion
    SET @MultilinesSafe = '<rows><row first="1"><cols><col first="1">' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@MultilinesSafe, @RowDelim, '</col></cols></row><row first="0"><cols><col first="0">'), @ColDelim, '</col><col>') + '</col></cols></row></rows>'
    SET @MultilinesXml = @MultilinesSafe
    --PRINT CAST(@MultilinesXml AS VARCHAR(MAX))

    -- extract Column names
    SELECT
        IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS ID,
        t.n.query('.').value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)') AS ColName
    INTO #RawDataColumnnames
    FROM @MultilinesXml.nodes('/rows/row[@first="1"]/cols/col') AS t(n) -- just first row
    ALTER TABLE #RawDataColumnnames ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_#RawDataColumnnames] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ID)
    -- now tidy any strange characters in column name
    UPDATE T SET ColName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ColName, '.', '_'), ' ', '_'), '[', ''), ']', ''), '.', ''), '$', '') FROM #RawDataColumnnames T

    -- create output table
    SET @SQL = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @TableName + ''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + @TableName
    --PRINT 'TableDelete SQL=' + @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql  @SQL

    SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '('
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CASE T.ID WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END
        + CHAR(13) + '['+ T.ColName + '] VARCHAR(4000) NULL'
    FROM #RawDataColumnnames T
    ORDER BY ID
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ')'
    --PRINT 'TableCreate SQL=' + @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql  @SQL

    -- insert data into output table
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' SELECT '
    SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CONCAT(CHAR(13)
        , CASE T.ID WHEN 1 THEN ' ' ELSE ',' END
        , ' t.n.value(''col[', T.ID, ']'', ''VARCHAR(4000)'') AS TheCol', T.ID)
    FROM #RawDataColumnnames T
    ORDER BY ID
    SET @SQL = @SQL + CONCAT(CHAR(13), 'FROM @TheXml.nodes(''/rows/row[@first="0"]/cols'') as t(n)')
    --PRINT 'Insert SQL=' + @SQL
    SET @ParamDef = N'@TheXml XML'
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSql  @SQL, @ParamDef, @TheXml=@MultilinesXml

GO
```

Example conversion (note that spaces are tabs!):

```
    EXEC dbo.uspDumpMultilinesWithHeaderIntoTable 'Deleteme', 'Left Centre  Right
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I'
```

into (via 'SELECT * FROM deleteme')

```
Left    Centre  Right
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
```

Note that this is pragmatic code, written not as an efficiency exercise but to get a job done.

## EDIT # Improved code (empty column name work-around, adds primary key)

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.uspDumpMultilinesWithHeaderIntoTable', 'P') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE dbo.uspDumpMultilinesWithHeaderIntoTable; 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspDumpMultilinesWithHeaderIntoTable @TableName VARCHAR(127), @Multilines VARCHAR(MAX), @ColDelimDefault VARCHAR(9) = NULL, @Debug BIT = NULL
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RawData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #RawData
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RawDataColumnnames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #RawDataColumnnames
DECLARE @Msg VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PosCr INT, @PosNl INT, @TypeRowDelim VARCHAR(20)

-- work out type of row delimiter(s)
SET @PosCr = CHARINDEX(CHAR(13), @Multilines)
SET @PosNl = CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @Multilines)
SET @TypeRowDelim = CASE
    WHEN @PosCr = @PosNl + 1 THEN 'NL_CR'
    WHEN @PosCr = @PosNl - 1 THEN 'CR_NL'
    WHEN @PosCr = 0 AND @PosNl > 0 THEN 'NL'
    WHEN @PosCr > 0 AND @PosNl = 0 THEN 'CR'
    ELSE CONCAT('? CR@', @PosCr, ', NL@', @PosNl, ' is unexpected') END

-- CR(x0d) is a 'good' row delimiter - make the data fit
DECLARE @RowDelim VARCHAR(9)

DECLARE @MultilinesSafe VARCHAR(MAX)
IF @TypeRowDelim = 'CR_NL' OR @TypeRowDelim = 'NL_CR' BEGIN
    SET @RowDelim = '&#x0d;'
    SET @MultilinesSafe = REPLACE(@Multilines, CHAR(10), '')    -- strip LF
    SET @MultilinesSafe = (SELECT @MultilinesSafe FOR XML PATH(''))  -- escape any XML confusion
END 
ELSE IF @TypeRowDelim = 'CR' BEGIN
    SET @RowDelim = '&#x0d;'
    SET @MultilinesSafe = @Multilines
    SET @MultilinesSafe = (SELECT @MultilinesSafe FOR XML PATH(''))  -- escape any XML confusion
END
ELSE IF @TypeRowDelim = 'NL' BEGIN
    SET @RowDelim = '&#x0d;'
    SET @MultilinesSafe = REPLACE(@Multilines, CHAR(10), CHAR(13))  -- change LF to CR
    SET @MultilinesSafe = (SELECT @MultilinesSafe FOR XML PATH(''))  -- escape any XML confusion
END
ELSE
    RAISERROR(@TypeRowDelim , 10, 10)

DECLARE @ColDelim VARCHAR(9) = COALESCE(@ColDelimDefault, CHAR(9))
DECLARE @MultilinesXml XML
DECLARE @ColumnNamesAsString VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000), @ParamDef NVARCHAR(4000)

IF @Debug = 1 BEGIN
    SET @Msg = CONCAT('TN=<', @TableName, '>, TypeRowDelim=<', @TypeRowDelim, '>, RowDelim(XML)=<', @RowDelim, '>, ColDelim=<', @ColDelim, '>, LEN(@Multilines)=', LEN(@Multilines))
    PRINT @Msg
END

SET @MultilinesSafe = '<rows><row first="1"><cols><col first="1">' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@MultilinesSafe, @RowDelim, '</col></cols></row><row first="0"><cols><col first="0">'), @ColDelim, '</col><col>') + '</col></cols></row></rows>'
SET @MultilinesXml = @MultilinesSafe
--IF @Debug = 1 PRINT CAST(@MultilinesXml AS VARCHAR(MAX))

-- extract Column names
SELECT
    IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) AS ID,
    t.n.query('.').value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)') AS ColName
INTO #RawDataColumnnames
FROM @MultilinesXml.nodes('/rows/row[@first="1"]/cols/col') AS t(n) -- just first row
ALTER TABLE #RawDataColumnnames ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_#RawDataColumnnames] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ID)
-- now tidy any strange characters in column name
UPDATE T SET ColName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ColName, '.', '_'), ' ', '_'), '[', ''), ']', ''), '.', ''), '$', '') FROM #RawDataColumnnames T
-- now fix any empty column names
UPDATE T SET ColName = CONCAT('_Col_', ID, '_') FROM #RawDataColumnnames T WHERE ColName = ''

IF @Debug = 1 BEGIN
    SET @Msg = CONCAT('#Cols(FromHdr)=', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #RawDataColumnnames) )
    PRINT @Msg
END

-- create output table
SET @SQL = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @TableName + ''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + @TableName
--PRINT 'TableDelete SQL=' + @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql  @SQL

SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '('

SET @SQL = @SQL + '[_Row_PK_] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,'   -- PK

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CASE T.ID WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END
    + CHAR(13) + '['+ T.ColName + '] VARCHAR(4000) NULL'
FROM #RawDataColumnnames T
ORDER BY ID

SET @SQL = @SQL + ')'
--PRINT 'TableCreate SQL=' + @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql  @SQL

-- insert data into output table
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TableName + ' SELECT '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CONCAT(CHAR(13)
    , CASE T.ID WHEN 1 THEN ' ' ELSE ',' END
    , ' t.n.value(''col[', T.ID, ']'', ''VARCHAR(4000)'') AS TheCol', T.ID)
FROM #RawDataColumnnames T
ORDER BY ID
SET @SQL = @SQL + CONCAT(CHAR(13), 'FROM @TheXml.nodes(''/rows/row[@first="0"]/cols'') as t(n)')
--PRINT 'Insert SQL=' + @SQL
SET @ParamDef = N'@TheXml XML'
EXEC sp_ExecuteSql  @SQL, @ParamDef, @TheXml=@MultilinesXml

GO
```

Running this with

```
    EXEC dbo.uspDumpMultilinesWithHeaderIntoTable  'Deleteme', 'Left        Right
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I'
```

Results in

```
_Row_PK_    Left    _Col_2_ Right
1   A   B   C
2   D   E   F
3   G   H   I
```