# Excel VBA - Table to CSV HTTP Post

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to take a table with n Columns and n Rows and make a CSV variable/string in which I can send through a HTTP Post.

I have only been able to find solutions to create a CSV File. But, i do not want to create a File, I just want to send the final result through a HTTP Post. I know how to do the HTTP Post, I just don't know how to get the CSV to a variable/string and send without creating a File.

Comment: Don't write to a file but keep the content in a variable instead.

Comment: I believe that's the part I'm not sure on doing, which is why I asked the question here. An example would be great!

Comment: Various approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597999/turn-excel-range-into-vba-string

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll go through those and see what i can come up with. It would be nice if someone has already produced a similar result.

Comment: Tim thanks for that link! That helped me get what i needed