# Using VBA to select Excel Tabs based on a name range

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

Is there a way to convert the line of code below from a static list of excel chartsheets to one that references a range of cells that names the chart sheets I want to select?

Ultimately, I would like the user to go to a worksheet named "scratchpad", enter the names of the chartsheets they want to export in a range of cells within that sheet, and have VBA select those chartsheets.

I tried to reference an excel named range in the "scratchpad" worksheet, but it didn't work.

Current static line of code:

```
Sheets(Array("Alpha Chart", "P&G Chart", "Quality Chart", "Sentiment Chart", "Value Chart")).Select
```

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a valid error description.

Comment: If you have a named range and you want to pass its values to `Sheets()`, the [lazy way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8934237/11683) is `sheets(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("name").value)).select`.