# Performing range(array(x)) on an entire array instead of going element-by-element

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm writing a macro that will take a changing list of numbers (placed in an array), copy the equivalent slides from a powerpoint, and then paste the selected slides into another powerpoint (so if the numbers are 2, 5, and 7, the macro will copy/paste powerpoint slides 2, 5, and 7). I can make it work with individual array elements, but can't figure out how to pass all array elements at once into the selection. These are the relevant lines of code:

```
Dim NumberList() As Variant
NumberList= Range("A11", Range("A10").End(xlDown))
OriginalPowerpoint.Slides.Range(Array(NumberList(1, 1), NumberList(3, 1))).Copy
      'this is the line I'm having trouble with
NewPowerpoint.Slides.Paste -1
```

The above code does work, but I want to pass the entire NumberList into Array() in the third line, as opposed to the current samples of NumberList(1,1) and NumberList(3,1). Just putting in "NumberList" or "NumberList()" doesn't work, and I'd really like to avoid making this a loop for efficiency reasons. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Range.Value` for a multicell range will return a 2D array, while the `Array()` produces a 1D array. So you will have to copy the 2D array into a 1D array in some form. You can be lazy and just [pass it to `Transpose()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8934237/11683), or loop over the cells individually and fill a pre-allocated 1D array, or loop over the returned 2D array and copy it into a pre-allocated 1D array.

Comment: `OriginalPowerpoint.Slides(NumberList).Copy` should be what your aiming for, but the question is what's in those cells in `Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown))`?

Answer (score 0):

### PowerPoint Slides Array feat 'write1D'

If your posted example works, this should do the trick (not tested).

```
Option Explicit

Sub PowerP()

    Dim NumberList As Variant

    NumberList = Range("A11", Range("A11").End(xlDown))
    NumberList = write1D(NumberList)
    OriginalPowerpoint.Slides(NumberList).Copy

End Sub

Function write1D(ColumnArray As Variant, _
  Optional ColumnIndex As Long = 1) As Variant
    Dim Source As Variant, i As Long
    ReDim Source(UBound(ColumnArray) - LBound(ColumnArray))
    For i = LBound(ColumnArray) To UBound(ColumnArray)
        Source(i - LBound(ColumnArray)) _
          = ColumnArray(i, LBound(ColumnArray, 2) + ColumnIndex - 1)
    Next i
    write1D = Source
End Function
```